# Symfony admin generator - One-to-one relationships

Tags: php, symfony1, generator, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I have in my model defined two entities linked by a one-to-one relationship:

```
User:  
  columns: 
    home_address_id: integer
  relations:
    HomeAddress:
      class: Address
      local: home_address_id
      foreignType: one

Address:
  columns: 
    zip: string
    city: string
```

When I use the generator, my form includes all fields of the User object, including a dropdown list to select an address.

What I would like is to be able to enter directly the Zip and City of the user's home address. How to request this to be generated in the generator.yml file? Do I have to implement some code to do it myself or is there a way for it to be automatic?

Comment: I don't see the School object in your example, but I'm also wondering, what's the point of a one to one relationship?  Why not put the zip and city columns in your User object?

Comment: The address table has more fields. Reasons: the address can be re-used in other places (shipping address, building address, ...) plus in the generated classes, you can have methods specific to addresses and that have nothing to do with the User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't designed anything with a one to one relationship or seen it in the symfony docs.  It looks to me like it's treating it the same as a one to many relationship.

I think all you have to do to work around it, though, is to [use embedded forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms).

Comment: Still need to polish the solution but it worked nicely. Thanks!